# GSuite Admin SDK > Directory API: How do I add values to a custom schema for a user?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

We are setting up some automation around SSO into AWS, but I have run into a problem.

There is a custom user attribute called `AWSLab`, and if a user does not have any `IAMRole` values populated for this attribute, then I need to add one.

The `IAMRole` field has **Info type** set to **Text** and **No. of values** set to **Multi-value** on the GSuite side, so I am putting it into an array for this API request.

Also, when I do a `GET` on the user and look at other schemas attached, I see this key named `type` set to `work` so I include that too.

Below is my function in Google Apps Script:

```
function check_user_access(){
  var email = 'user@domain.com';
  var role = [
    'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/User',
    'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:saml-provider/GoogleAppsProvider'
  ].join(',')

  optArgs = {
    projection: "full"
  }

  var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email, optArgs)
  var schema = user.customSchemas

  Logger.log("typeof(schema): %s", typeof(schema))

  if(schema["AWSLab"]) {
    Logger.log("schema[\"AWSLab\"] found on user '%s': %s", email, schema["AWSLab"])
  } else {
    Logger.log("schema[\"AWSLab\"] not found! Updating...")

    Logger.log("schema before:\n\n%s\n", JSON.stringify(schema))
    schema["AWSLab"] = { "IAMRole": [{ "type": "work", "value": role }] }
    Logger.log("schema after:\n\n%s\n", JSON.stringify(schema))

    AdminDirectory.Users.update(userFull, email) // line 35
  }
}
```

When this function runs, I see this error:

```
Invalid Input: [AWSLab] (line 35, file "Labs")
```

I have some extra lines in there right now, to output some details for troubleshooting, but it's not helping me see the problem.

Comment: Did you check the [Directory API: Custom User Fields](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas) ?

Comment: I did not, but [this GET schemas list method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/schemas/list) would have helped to troubleshoot also. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was with the name of the custom schema.

At creation, the schema had a different name which was then edited at some point.

The key to figuring this out was populating the schema fields in question on a user with some dummy data, then pulling the user out via the API with a `GET` and examining the JSON.